# Popping up different forms respectively to what is typed in an input form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, authentication

Good morning, I modified a little a tutorial code to make it show different account creation forms respectively to a version name typed in an input form called version. Whatever version name I will type in here the option meant for a full version appears. I am using bootstrap and jquery. What is wrong with it?

```
                <?php  
                if(isset($_SESSION['username']))  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <h1>Welcome - <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1><br />

                     <?php if ($_SESSION['version'] = "full") { ?>
  <form action="fullfinalinserting.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="yname"> Username</label>
                      <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="url">Your Site URL</label>
                      <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact1"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact1" name="contact1" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact2"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact2" name="contact2" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact3"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact3" name="contact3" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact4"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact4" name="contact4" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="farewell"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="farewell" name="farewell" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="ppname"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="ppname" name="ppname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color1"  >
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color2"  >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="message"></label>
                      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <fieldset>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="file" name="uploadfile" multiple class="btn btn-primary" required>
                  </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="file" name="uploadfile2" multiple class="btn btn-primary" required>
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld_eGoUAAAAAN-KLDMr1b3Kepypf3OBp0hNWF_H"></div>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                     <a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a>  
                </div>  
                     <?php 
                     } else if ($_SESSION['version'] = "deluxe") { ?>


             <form action="deluxefinalinserting.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="yname">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="url"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="email"></label>
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact1"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact1" name="contact1" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact2"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact2" name="contact2" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact3"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact3" name="contact3" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact4"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact4" name="contact4" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="ppname"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="ppname" name="ppname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color1"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color2"  >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">

                  </div>
                  <fieldset>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="file" name="uploadfile" multiple class="btn btn-primary" required>
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld_eGoUAAAAAN-KLDMr1b3Kepypf3OBp0hNWF_H"></div>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                      <?php 
                     }  else if ($_SESSION['version'] = "standard") { ?>

                            <form action="standardfinalinserting.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="yname">Userbame</label>
                      <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="url"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="email"></label>
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="ppname"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="ppname" name="ppname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color1" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color2" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">

                  </div>
                  <fieldset>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="file" name="uploadfile" multiple class="btn btn-primary" required>
                  </fieldset>
                   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld_eGoUAAAAAN-KLDMr1b3Kepypf3OBp0hNWF_H"></div>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                </form>

                      <?php 
                     }  else if ($_SESSION['version'] = "premium") { ?>

                       <form action="premiumfinalinserting.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="yname">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="url"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="email"></label>
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact1"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact1" name="contact1" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact2"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact2" name="contact2" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact3"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact3" name="contact3" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="contact4"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="contact4" name="contact4" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="farewell"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="farewell" name="farewell" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="ppname"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="ppname" name="ppname" class="form-control " required>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color1"  >
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                      <label for="color"></label>
                      <input type="color" id="color" name="color2"  >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="message"></label>
                      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <fieldset>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="file" name="uploadfile" multiple class="btn btn-primary" required />
                  </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                  <legend></legend>
                  <input type="file" name="uploadfile2" multiple class="btn btn-primary" required />
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld_eGoUAAAAAN-KLDMr1b3Kepypf3OBp0hNWF_H"></div>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <?php  
                     } }  
                else  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <button type="button" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                ?>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In conditions always use operators like:

for equal to: `==`

for not equal to: `!=`

for greater then: `>`

for smaller then: `<`

for greater then or equal to: `>=`

for smaller then or equal to: `<=`

for example:-

```
if(var1==var2){
//code block
}
```

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the statements here.
‘full’ version is the first statement:

Instead of checking  $_SESSION[‘version’] == ‘full’
It’s sets the session with $_SESSION[‘version’] = ‘full’

So double the equal sign ;)

Comment: Ok so all the version session statements have a double equal character. Did you unset the session also before you did a new test? Also you may remove the else after most checks because I think $_SESSION may contain only one string value.  Like    } else if (..) {    change it into  } if (..) {